# Streamlining / Optimizing conditional Rules in a rule engine using ML techniques

Tags: optimization, association-rules, credit-scoring, tuning

The problem is defined as follows :

We are dealing with a Rule engine used to classify a credit risk as 'Good', 'Medium' or 'bad'. Say the rule engine which has say 10 rules. These rules are hierchical/ Reflexive in nature i.e. say :

Customer A comes in to apply for a product - he has to answer say 10 questions which could trigger those 10 rules if answered Yes. Say for e.g. the first question is :

1. Do u have any credit default in past ?

   - Customer answers "Yes". This triggers say "default rule" and shoots the below question

1.1 : How long back did the default occur ?

- Action if time <2 years , trigger question 1.2 else Give decision "Good"
- Say customer answers 1 year and this triggers 1.2

1.2 How much was the default amount?

- Action if amount > 1000 dollars , trigger question 1.3 else Give decision "Medium"
- Say customer answers 5000 and this triggers 1.3 which is the final question in this rule

1.3 Was bankruptcy declared ?

- if Yes give decision "Bad"
- if No give decision "Bad"
- if in process , give decision "Bad"

Now the there could be different pathways for each customer based no their answers i.e. some just answer Q1.1 , Some go to Q1.1 & Q1.2 and some may go to Q1.1 , Q1.2 and Q1.3 and can get different decisions based on what they answer.

Problem statement is : Predicting the final decision - Good , Medium , Bad with minimal questions in this rule i.e. streamline if Q1.3 adds any value or not? for e.g. above we can stop at Q1.2 only where if default amount is > 1000 dollars , the outcome is always bad.

The problem is not trivial as in actual scenarios there are 100s of rules with long and multiple possible pathways. The idea is to streamline these rules (reduce the length) while achieving similar/ same level results performance.  What possible approaches can be applied here if we build a model say for each rule to streamline it ?

So far my ideation :

1. Select top X rules with domain and volume considerations
2. Build model with various questions in pathway and their answers as variables and final outcome. Wherever question was not triggered , it will be NA.
3. See SHAP/additive value or information gain of questions where triggered to see if they add any value
4. Streamline and reduce (remove variables) based on 3.
5. rebuild model and compare accuracy with reduced variables(reduced questions)

One more consideration to keep in mind is Q1.3 is depending on Q1.2 and Q1.2 is on Q1.1 So we can't reduce the question in between say Q1.2 and leave Q1.3 and Q1.1

Comment: I believe the most common way to achieve this streamlined assessment is to first build an application scorecard. If the score is above 800 (for example - note that the exact threshold would be set by business), then the customer(s) would bypass a set of rules essentially getting a free pass (for some rules at least).

Answer (score 1):

You could seek inspiration in a completely different area of research, psychometry. Psychometrists have broad literature on [computerized adaptive testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computerized_adaptive_testing), where the problem statement is similar: you want to assess some trait of a person, using a computerized questionnaire, using as small a number of questions as possible. It is not something that I did, so I would encourage you to check the references in the Wikipedia's article and possibly google for some more resources.

Comment: I did check them and the approaches are too generic and not what i was looking at. Will read through them in detail further.